# Example on proving continuity in metric spaces

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

Prove that $f(x)=x+y^2+xy$ is continuous as a function $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the metric $d_1(x,y)=|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|$. (assume that on $\mathbb{R}$ we consider the usual absolute value metric).

I am at a loss as to how to prove them, because I am not quite sure on how to bound it such that it will be $<\epsilon$.

Comment: This is a complicated question. There's no special tricks, just many of the standard tricks strung together. So, what about proving some simpler versions of this question? For example, can you show that $f(x, y) = x$ is continuous? What about $f(x, y) = y^2$? If you can do both of these, try showing $f(x, y) = x + y^2$ is continuous. Build yourself up to the full function.

Comment: maybe it helps if you think how you'd write it down using the euclidiean metric in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\vert x - y \vert < \varepsilon$. Which is the same as $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$. In other words, finding a bounding $\varepsilon$ leads to $d_1(x,y) = \vert x_1 - y_1\vert + \vert x_2 - y_2 \vert < \varepsilon$

Comment: Show that sums/products of continuous functions $\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<\epsilon <1$. Fix $(x,y)$. Let us prove continuity at this point. $$|(x+y^{2}+xy)-(x'+y'^{2}+x'y')|$$ $$\leq |x-x'|+ |y-y'|(2|y|+|y-y'|)+|x||y-y'|+|y'||x-x'|$$. It is enough to make sure that $|x-x'|<\epsilon /4, |x-x'|<\epsilon /{4(|y|+1)},|y-y'| <\epsilon /(4|x|)$ and $|y-y'| <\epsilon/ {4(2|y|+1)}$